# uWSGI downtime when restart

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I have a problem with uwsgi everytime I restart the server when I have a code updates.

1. When I restart the uwsgi using "sudo restart accounting", there's a small gap between stop and start instance that results to downtime and stops all the current request.
2. When I try "sudo reload accounting", it works but my memory goes up (double). When I run the command "ps aux | grep accounting", it shows that I have 10 running processes (accounting.ini) instead of 5 and it freezes up my server when the memory hits the limit.

**accounting.ini**

[image]

I am running

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Django 1.9
- nginx 1.4.6
- uwsgi 2.0.12

Comment: Additionaly to my answer, consider lowering number of processes since your server is not capable of running 10

Comment: my processes currently have 5. By the way, how should I know how many processes should I set? I am running 4gb RAM with 15mb memory. Please see this link. https://pasteboard.co/HIfZxxh.png

Comment: I've updated my answer with another solution proposition `Chain reloads` try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how uwsgi does graceful reload. Keeps old processes until requests are served and creates new ones that will take over incoming requests.

Read [Things that could go wrong](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html#things-go-wrong)

> Do not forget, your workers/threads that are still running requests
>   could block the reload (for various reasons) for more seconds than
>   your proxy server could tolerate.

And this

> Another important step of graceful reload is to avoid destroying
>   workers/threads that are still managing requests. Obviously requests
>   could be stuck, so you should have a timeout for running workers (in
>   uWSGI it is called the “worker’s mercy” and it has a default value of
>   60 seconds).

So i would recommend trying [worker-reload-mercy](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html?highlight=mercy#worker-reload-mercy)

Default value is to wait 60 seconds, just lower it to something that your server can handle.

Tell me if it worked.

---

### Uwsgi chain reload

This is another try to fix your issue. As you mentioned your uwsgi workers are restarting in a manner described below:

1. send `SIGHUP` signal to the master
2. Wait for running workers.
3. Close all of the file descriptors except the ones mapped to sockets.
4. Call exec() on itself.

One of the cons of this kind of reload might be stuck workers. 
Additionaly you report that your server crashes when uwsgi maintains 10 proceses (5 old and 5 new ones).

I propose trying **chain reload**. DIrect quote from documentation explains this kind of reload best:

> When triggered, it will **restart one worker at time**, and the following worker is not reloaded until the previous one is ready to accept new requests.

It means that you will not have 10 processes on your server but only 5.

Config that should work:

```
# your .ini file
lazy-apps = true
touch-chain-reload = /path/to/reloadFile
```

Some resources on chain reload and other kinds are in links below:

[Chain reloading uwsgi docs](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html?highlight=chain#chain-reloading-lazy-apps)

[uWSGI graceful Python code deploy](http://zarnovican.github.io/2016/02/15/uwsgi-graceful-reload/#pre-fork-vs-lazy-app)

Comment: Hi Kamil. Thanks you again. I really appreciate it. 

Okay, I will let you know it it worked.

Comment: I updated my .ini file. But when I reload, the process still doubles. I waited for how many minutes but the old processes is still taking up a memory.


https://pasteboard.co/HIgQGLp.png

and 
https://pasteboard.co/HIgRMWQ.png

Comment: @aldesabido i don't see that you set `worker-reload-mercy` in `ini` file. How much traffic your service takes? Can you tell me some statistics on request response times?

Comment: If you say response time you mean how long would it take to load the page? or in every page requests.. There are times that the system is fast but gets slower when the traffic increases.

Comment: Should I increase my hardware specs to increase the number of processes/workers?

Comment: I would like to see time plots of cpu, memory, requests etc of your server. It should easily handle the reloading. You could also paste uwsgi logs when during reload. Everything that can give information what is going on.