# Django - How to reload uwsgi in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: django, ubuntu-16.04, uwsgi, systemctl

I have a project running in Ubuntu 16.04 with uWSGI. There are times that I don't want to use restart command and just want to reload the project when I have changes.

When I was still using ubuntu 14.04, I can just use the following commands.

to reload:

```
sudo reload projectname
```

to restart

```
sudo restart projectname
```

---

now when I try to restart in Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo systemctl restart uwsgi
```

When I try to reload using this command

```
sudo systemctl reload uwsgi
```

This is the error message

```
Failed to reload uwsgi.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit uwsgi.service.
```

Screenshot of the error message.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are running uwsgi in Emperor mode.

That means that emperor process is governing its vassals (actual uwsgi processes that run your Django app) and it simply doesn't have reload job in its systemd unit.

Instead you should try just touching the `.ini` file of your app.

```
touch path/to/payroll.ini
```

Below are couple of resources on Uwsgi, systemd and Emperor mode

[Systemd and Uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Systemd.html?highlight=systemd#)

[Uwsgi Emperor Mode and Django](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#emperor-mode)

Comment: HI Kamil. Thank it works. Does touching the file has the same effect as "reload" command? I think it's really weird.

Comment: Yes it is the same. Here are more resources that would help you. I recommend reading uwsgi docs. https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Management.html#reloading-the-server https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/articles/TheArtOfGracefulReloading.html if my answer helped please accept it for future searching answer for the problem

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi Kamil, I have another problem with my Django + uwsgi.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46147864/uwsgi-downtime-when-restart

If you have time, could you please answer this one too? Thanks!